# Stripe apply coupon code on invoice created by updating Subscription Item

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-processing

I am trying to add a new subscription item to an already created subscription using Stripe and I am providing proration_behaviour: 'always invoice' that immediately creates an invoice for the customer to be paid.
I also want to apply a coupon code for that invoice but I can't find any way to do that with Stripe because the invoice is automatically finalized by Stripe and cannot be updated.
Is there any way to apply that coupon code before the invoice is finalized? Or is there any way to stop Stipe from automatically finalizing the invoice in case of an update of a subscription item but leave it as draft so that updating is enabled?

```
Stripe::SubscriptionItem.update(
        'sub_item_id',
        proration_behavior: 'always_invoice',
        payment_behavior: 'default_incomplete',
        quantity: 10
)
```

https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_items/update

I am using this documentation for updating my subscription item and it seems that isn't any way to manage the created invoice or to attach a coupon or promo code to that particular invoice

Answer (score 0):

You would need to switch away from the Update SubscriptionItem [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_items/update) and use the Update Subscription [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update) instead. By doing this, you can both change the items associated with that Subscription and pass a coupon at the same time.

Note that `items` as a parameter will "merge" the results. So if you have a Subscription with 2 items and you want to change the first one from Price A to Price B, you have to explicitly pass that subscription item to be updated like this:

```
items: [
  {
    id: 'si_123',
    price: 'price_B',
    quantity: 10,
  }
]
```